# Game freezes and shows Performed 6 layouts in a row. Skipping

Tags: java, android, multithreading, freeze

Okay, so i've been trying to make smooth jumps in a ***2D pure android with no game engine*** for a week now. I am using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` right now.

So i have a variable called FPS. This is how many time the character has to go up before reaching 180 Y value;

Note: `FPS` is not really Frames per Second in the whole game.

When `FPS` is set to 45, the app never freezes ***(Unless I repeatly spam the jump button)***

But on 90, ***AT RANDOM OCCASIONS WHEN I PLAY THE GAME*** the game FREEZES and logcat indicates:

```
E/WindowManager: Performed 6 layouts in a row. Skipping
```

It dosent matter what I use (EX: `Handler` `Runnable` and `Thread`), app

Here is the jump code:

```
    public void jump() {

    final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

    if(!isRunning) {
        executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            boolean moveUpBln = true;
            int timesLooped = 0;
            float FPS = 90; //Never freezes with value of 45 (or under)
            float charMovementFPS = 180 / FPS;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(moveUpBln) {
                    isRunning = true;

                    characterModel.setY(characterModel.getY() - charMovementFPS);
                    if (timesLooped == FPS || timesLooped > FPS) {
                        moveUpBln = false;
                        timesLooped = -1;

                    }
                    timesLooped++;
                }else{
                    isRunning = true;

                    characterModel.setY(characterModel.getY() + charMovementFPS);
                    if (timesLooped == FPS || timesLooped > FPS) {
                        executor.shutdownNow();
                        isRunning = false;
                    }
                    timesLooped++;
                }

            }

        }, 0, 3, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    }
}
```

***NOTE: the -1 isn't the problem, this is intentional***

What are these `layouts` the logcat is talking about? Am I putting too much pressure on my Non-Engine game?

Comment: You don't really describe how you are drawing items. The fact that you are using a count of loops mechanism seems jank prone due to thread stalls. As it appears that you are writing a game/game like app in Java, I recommend watching [Google I/O 2009 - Writing Real-Time Games for Android](https://youtu.be/U4Bk5rmIpic) and the followup [Google I/O 2010 - Writing real-time games for Android redux](https://youtu.be/7-62tRHLcHk). While dated I think it covers the basic issues well.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look

Comment: @MorrisonChang Those videos are 1 hour ***each***. I would understand 30 minutes or even 40, but these are too long.

Comment: No one is asking you to watch the videos in one sitting or not have repeated viewing. Once your head is full, stop and go back to it in a few days if you think its worth your time. I reference those videos as the speaker describes the issues he encountered working on his 2D platform game back when Android was new.